# How to display multiple lines in a JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to create a `JTable` like the below picture:[image]

Which `java` class will be used and possibly how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically you can put any type of `JComponents` to the `JTable` cell, depends of if is contents editable, thats talking me about follows

- `JTable` with one `TableColumn` without `TableHeader`
- `JPanel` (`GridBagLayout`) with `JLabels` or `JTextFields`
- `JList`

Answer (score 18):

Multiline `JTable` cell can make using a customized `TableCellRenderer` easily. Use following steps to create the `TableCellRenderer`.

**Step 1: Create `TableCellRenderer`**

Following code shows to create a multi-line `TableCellRenderer` for `String[]` values. It's possible to change the `String[]` into a `Vector` or an other `Collection` type

```
public class MultiLineTableCellRenderer extends JList<String> implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        //make multi line where the cell value is String[]
        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            setListData((String[]) value);
        }

        //cell backgroud color when selected
        if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
        } else {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.background"));
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Set `TableCellRenderer` into the `JTable`**

```
    MultiLineTableCellRenderer renderer = new MultiLineTableCellRenderer();

    //set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column class
    table.setDefaultRenderer(String[].class, renderer);

    //or, set TableCellRenderer into a specified JTable column
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(columnIndex).setCellRenderer(renderer);
```

**This is my tested screenshot:**

[image: Multi-line TableCellRenderer Test]

Comment: Upvoted for showing the most elegant way using TableCellRenderer.

Comment: @mekkanizer: I can go through it, if you share your code with me.

Comment: This needs some fiddling to autosize the row height though. Mind if I add that to your answer?

Comment: With foreground, if (isSelected) {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionBackground"));
            setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.selectionForeground"));
        } else {
            setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Table.background"));
            setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Table.foreground"));
        }

Answer (score 1):

This will not work if you use a `DefaultTableModel`. You have to use a custom model for your table that extends `AbstractTableModel` and have to override the method `getColumnClass()`, along with other abstract methods.

You will also set your table row height [as mentioned in a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955595/how-to-display-multiple-lines-in-a-jtable-cell#comment83054272_32793088).

The [official documentation from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) clarifies this.

Answer (score 0):

```
jTable1.setShowGrid(true);
```

Try this code :)

Answer (score 0):

```
jTable1.setShowHorizontalLines(true); // only HorizontalLines
  jTable1.setShowVerticalLines(true); //  only VerticalLines
  jTable1.setShowGrid(true);          // show Horizontal and Vertical
  jTable1.setGridColor(Color.yellow); // change line color
```

Comment: While this code may solve the issue, a few words of explanation would be of value to the current and future users.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the `TableCellRenderer` based on `JList<String>` as suggested by Channa Jayamuni you can **build a multi-line renderer on top of the `DefaultTableCellRenderer`** as well. The trick is to use the HTML feature of the `JLabel` component and adjust the line height accordingly. This preserves more of the features of the default renderer.

Activating this renderer for all Strings will do what you want in most cases:

```
setDefaultRenderer(String.class, new MultiLineCellRenderer());
```

The solution handles **automatic line height** to some degree. I.e. it will *not decrease* the height of a table line if the content is updated with less lines. This is a quite complex task because it depends on the content of any other cell in the same line as well.

```
/** Variant of DefaultTableCellRenderer that automatically switches
 *  to multi-line HTML when the value contains newlines. */
class MultiLineCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
  @Override public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
    Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
  { Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    int height = c.getPreferredSize().height;
    if (table.getRowHeight(row) < height)
      table.setRowHeight(row, height);
    return c;
  }

  @Override protected void setValue(Object value)
  { if (value instanceof String)
    { String sVal = (String)value;
      if (sVal.indexOf('\n') >= 0 && // any newline?
        !(sVal.startsWith("<html>") && sVal.endsWith("</html>"))) // already HTML?
        value = "<html><nobr>" + htmlEncodeLines(sVal) + "</nobr></html>";
    }
    super.setValue(value);
  }

  /** Encode string as HTML. Convert newlines to &lt;br&gt; as well.
   * @param s String to encode.
   * @return Encoded string. */
  protected static String htmlEncodeLines(String s)
  { int i = indexOfAny(s, "<>&\n", 0); // find first char to encode
    if (i < 0)
      return s; // none
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(s.length() + 20);
    int j = 0;
    do
    { sb.append(s, j, i).append(htmlEncode(s.charAt(i)));
      i = indexOfAny(s, "<>&\n", j = i + 1);
    } while (i >= 0);
    sb.append(s, j, s.length());
    return sb.toString();
  }

  private static String htmlEncode(char c)
  { switch (c) {
    case '<': return "&lt;";
    case '>': return "&gt;";
    case '&': return "&amp;";
    case '\n': return "<br>";
    default: return Character.toString(c);
  } }

  private static int indexOfAny(String s, String set, int start)
  { for (int i = start; i < s.length(); ++i)
    if (set.indexOf(s.charAt(i)) >= 0)
      return i;
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

When any table has large volume of data, the use of scrollbar is applied in the JTable. The JScrollPane provides you to scrollable facility to scroll the scroll bar and you get all the contents. Simple example using JTable:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ScrollableJTable{
public static void main(String[] args) {
new ScrollableJTable();
}
public ScrollableJTable(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a Scrollable JTable!");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 String data[][] =
  {{"001","abc","xyz","wtwt","gwgw","tttr","rtrt"},
  {"002","rwtr","ttrt","rtttr","trt","rtrt","trtrd"},
  {"003","rtt","trt","trt","trrttr","trt","rtr"},
  {"004","trt","trtt","trtrt","rtrtt","trt","trrt"},
  {"001","rttr","trt","trt","trtr","trt","trttr"},
  ;
  JTable table = new JTable(data,col);
  JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
  header.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
  table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
  panel.add(pane);
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setSize(500,150);
  frame.setUndecorated(true);
  frame.getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.PLAIN_DIALOG);
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Now you can modify this table according to your requirements

Comment: at line `new JTable(data,col)`, `col` variable cannot be found. What's it?

Comment: This doesn't come near to answering the original poster's question. He wants multiple lines in a table cell.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i just showed a demo for this question so that accordingly he can modify it

Comment: @harry: not quite. It shows an example of a JTable, yes, but that can easily be obtained from the tutorials. The very difficult part is explaining or showing how to do multiple lines in a JTable cell, and your answer doesn't address this at all, as opposed to mKorbel's good answer.