# How can I render a JList inside a JTable cell?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, jlist

In three of the columns of my JTable that I have set up I would like to have a list in each cell of the column. I'm not sure where to start on possibly creating a custom cell renderer class if that's the best option? My goal is to list the group names each on their own line in each cell, and expand the cell height as new lines are added. Each group will have an AdmType and Admitted entry, so I will also need to figure out how to add another checkbox to the Admitted column cell for every new Group entry.

[image: My JTable]

Comment: why ???, is possible to rendering JList, JTree as TableCellRenderer / TableCellEditor, search for TreeTable, good one is JXTreeTable, Outline from Netbeans, rest (talking about good one) aren't free

Comment: As mKorbel pointed out, something like a JXTreeTable would definitely be less of a hassle instead of cooking up your own renderer/editor for a JList style cell.

Comment: Would a JXTreeTable display it in a tree-like fashion though and not similar to a list? Or is there flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

This below solution did not work for me, but it clearly worked for the person who posted a screen shot of their success. My problems may be due to how I have my TableModel set up.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32793088/6867420