# Insert data from arraylist into cell of JTable

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable

I am working on a sign-in room app where a signed-in user can select visitors (max 3) to bring into the room with them. The class that handles visitors returns an `ArrayList` from which I was hoping to input the data into a cell of the `JTable` that displays users signed into the room. My problem is that I'm not entirely sure how to show each record in the list as a separate line in the particular cell of the `JTable`. 
Here's the main class (called SignBoardTest):

```html
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SignBoardTest {
 public static void main(String[] args)  {
  new SignBoardTest();  
 }

 private JFrame inOutFrame;
 
 private JPanel topPanel;
 private JPanel headerPanel;
 private JPanel mainPanel;
 private JPanel btnPanel;
 
 private JLabel roomLabel;

 private JButton addUserBtn;
 
 private JTable testTbl;

 private String[] answer = {"Eligible", "Not Eligible"};
 private String[] first = {"Jack", "Kelly", "Mike", "Lisa"};
 private String[] last = {"Donovan", "Marshall", "Jones", "Kinder"};
 
 private Visitor visitor;
 
 public SignBoardTest()
 {
  //place GUI components on JFrame's content pane
  inOutFrame = new JFrame("ISF Out of Office Board");
    
  topPanel = new JPanel();
  topPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  headerPanel = new JPanel();
  btnPanel = new JPanel();
  mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
  
  roomLabel = new JLabel("CLOSED AREA ROOM");
  roomLabel.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.BOLD, 30));
    
  addUserBtn = new JButton("Add user");

  String [] colNames = {"First Name", "Last Name",
    "Can be area monitor?", "Visitor(s)",
    "Status", ""};
  
  DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
  
  testTbl = new JTable(model);
  testTbl.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

  MultilineTableCellRenderer renderer = new MultilineTableCellRenderer();
  testTbl.setDefaultRenderer(String.class, renderer);
  testTbl.setRowHeight(testTbl.getRowHeight() * 3);
  

  JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(testTbl);
  mainPanel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  //action for add user feature
  addUserBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
  {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {
    
    String fName = first[new Random().nextInt(first.length)];
    String lName = last[new Random().nextInt(last.length)];
    String areaMonitor = answer[new Random().nextInt(answer.length)];
    
    model.addRow(new Object[] {fName, lName, areaMonitor, visitor, 
      "Logout", "Add/Remove Visitors"});
    
    BtnColumn visitorBtnColumn = new BtnColumn(testTbl, visitorMgmt, 5);
    visitorBtnColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
    
    BtnColumn logoutBtnColumn = new BtnColumn(testTbl, logout, 4);
    logoutBtnColumn.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_D);
   }
   
  });
  
  btnPanel.add(addUserBtn);
  
  headerPanel.add(roomLabel);
  
  topPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  topPanel.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
  
  topPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
  mainPanel.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));

  inOutFrame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
  inOutFrame.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  
  inOutFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  inOutFrame.pack();
  inOutFrame.setSize(1200, 1000); //default size in case screen is not full
  inOutFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  inOutFrame.setVisible(true);
  inOutFrame.setResizable(false);
  
}
 //handling of adding/removing users
 //with ButtonColumn class
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 Action visitorMgmt = new AbstractAction()
 {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   int row = testTbl.getSelectedRow();
   
   visitor = new Visitor();
   
   //make window modal
   visitor.setModalityType(Dialog.ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
   visitor.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   visitor.setVisible(true);
   
   if(visitor.getChoice() == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
   {
    for(String name : visitor.getVisitorList())
    {
     System.out.println("Adding user: " + name);
     
     String value = testTbl.getValueAt(row, 3) + name + " \n";
     testTbl.setValueAt(value, row, 3);
    }
   }
  }
 };
 
 //handle of logging out users using ButtonColumn class
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 Action logout = new AbstractAction()
 {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
   int row = testTbl.getSelectedRow();
   String first = testTbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString();
   String last = testTbl.getModel().getValueAt(row, 1).toString();
   String name = first.concat(" ").concat(last);
   
   if(doesUserHaveVisitors(row))
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
      "Visitors must be logged out or transferred to \nanother employee before signing out",
      "ERROR: ILLEGAL ACTION", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
   else
   { 
    int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
     "Are you sure you want to log out " + name + "?",
     "Logout confirmation", 
     JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
     JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    
    if(response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
    {
     JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
     int modelRow = Integer.valueOf(e.getActionCommand());
     ((DefaultTableModel)table.getModel()).removeRow(modelRow);
    }
   }
  }
 };
 
 private boolean doesUserHaveVisitors(int selectedRow)
 {
  Object value = testTbl.getValueAt(selectedRow, testTbl.getColumn("Visitor(s)").getModelIndex());
  
  if(value != null)
   return true;
  else
   return false;
 }
 
} //end class SignInBoard

/**
 * The MultiLineTableCellRenderer class is a customized to allow for multi-line
 * entry into a column of a JTable. This will allow for users to enter multiple
 * visitors (max 3) against their login record.
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MultilineTableCellRenderer extends JList<String> implements TableCellRenderer
{
 @Override
 public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
   boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
 {
  //make multi-line where the cell value is String[]
  if (value instanceof String[]) {
   setListData((String[]) value);
  }
  
  return this;
 }
}
```

The Visitor class which for users to manage visitors:

```html
import java.awt.Container;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Visitor extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
 
 private JButton newVisitorButton;
 private JButton doneButton;
 
 private JPanel contentPanel; //"body" of JDialog
 
 private JOptionPane visitorInputPane;
 
 private ArrayList<String> visitorList; //list to store visitors
 private int visitorCtr = 0; //counter for 
 
 public Visitor() {
  setTitle("Visitor Management");
  
  newVisitorButton = new JButton("New Visitor Entry");
  doneButton = new JButton("Done");
  
  contentPanel = new JPanel();
  contentPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  newVisitorButton.setAlignmentX(CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
  contentPanel.add(newVisitorButton);
  
  //since users can only have 3 visitors max,
  //list will be initialized to this size
  visitorList = new ArrayList<String>(3); 
  
  JButton[] buttonChoices = {doneButton};

  visitorInputPane = new JOptionPane(contentPanel,
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    null,
    buttonChoices,
    buttonChoices[0]);
  
  setContentPane(visitorInputPane);
  
  //handle the window closing - force
  //the user to use one of the buttons
  //to avoid closing w/out any action
  setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
  addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()  {
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
   {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(visitorInputPane,
      "Please close this using the Cancel button");
   }
  });
  
  pack();
  
  //listeners for button pushes
  
  doneButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    dispose();
   }
  });
  
  newVisitorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
   {

    if(visitorCtr > 2)
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(visitorInputPane, "Cannot add more visitors (max 3)!",
       "MAX LIMIT REACHED", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    else
    {
     contentPanel.add(new VisitorEntryPanel());
     pack();
     visitorCtr++;
    }

   }
  });
 
 }

 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 }
 
 //return visitor list
 public ArrayList<String> getVisitorList() {
  return visitorList;
 }
 
 //return choice from JDialog
 public int getChoice() {
  return visitorInputPane.getOptionType();
 }

 //custom JPanel inner class for adding
 //new user to list
 private class VisitorEntryPanel extends JPanel
 {
  private JLabel nameLabel;
  private JTextField nameField;
  private JButton removeVisitorButton;
  private JButton addVisitorButton;
  
  VisitorEntryPanel()
  {
   nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
   nameField = new JTextField(20);
   removeVisitorButton = new JButton("Remove");
   addVisitorButton = new JButton("Add");
   
   add(nameLabel);
   add(nameField);
   add(addVisitorButton);
   add(removeVisitorButton);
   
   removeVisitorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
     visitorList.remove(getVisitorName());
     
     Container myParent = removeVisitorButton.getParent();
     Container parent = myParent.getParent();
     parent.remove(myParent);
     parent.repaint();
     parent.revalidate();
     
     visitorCtr--;
     System.out.println("New visitor count: " + visitorCtr);
    }
   });
   
   addVisitorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {
     if(getVisitorName().length() != 0)
     {
      visitorList.add(getVisitorName());
      
      //disable button after good entry
      addVisitorButton.setEnabled(false);
     }
     else //can't submit null/empty name
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(visitorInputPane, "Visitor name cannot be empty!",
        "EMPTY NAME ENTERED", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    }
   });
  }
  
  public String getVisitorName() {
   return(nameField.getText().trim());
  }
  
 } //end class visitorPanel
 
} //end class Visitor
```

The button column class comes from the following [link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) (I didn't think it was necessary to repost it here). I used the answer provided by Channa in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955595/how-to-display-multiple-lines-in-a-jtable-cell) to create the custom `TableCellRenderer` to get the data from my `ArrayList` but I am not able to execute it properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I apologize - I thought I had done that when posting the code. I did strip out the extraneous code and got it down to MCVE, so I'm glad I did that correctly...

Comment: Still having troubles with this...I'm assuming it's not possible to set a specific column as multiline? It seems that most answers point to making the entire table multiline...