# How to bind ArrayList data from database into JComboBox in JTable?

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have successfully fetched data from database into JTable. But I'm having a little trouble to populate in JComboBox and then add it to JTable. Like I have stored ArrayList in String format in Documents Column. Now, I want a JComboBox in each row of Documents Column using that ArrayList in JTable.

Basically, replacing ArrayList String to JComboBox with that Array items.

In the documents column, the data is in form of array string:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsyNN.png]

> Jtable Code:

```
private static final DatabaseConnections databaseConnections = new DatabaseConnections();
private Thread thread; 

Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

public ConnectionRecordsPanel() {
    initComponents();
    SetData();
}

private void SetData(){
    columnNames.addElement("Customer Id");
    columnNames.addElement("Name");
    columnNames.addElement("DOB");
    columnNames.addElement("Gender");
    columnNames.addElement("Current Address");
    columnNames.addElement("Permanent Address");
    columnNames.addElement("Mobile Number");
    columnNames.addElement("Email Id");
    columnNames.addElement("Documents");
    columnNames.addElement("Gas Type");
    columnNames.addElement("Status");


    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Inside run");
                data = databaseConnections.getData(data);
                System.out.println("Inside run");
                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
                {
                    @Override
                    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
                    {
                        for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
                        {
                            Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                            if (o != null)
                            {
                                return o.getClass();
                            }
                        }
                        return Object.class;
                    }
                };
                jTable1.setModel(model);

                JComboBox jcb = new JComboBox();
                jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(9).setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(jcb));
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ConnectionRecordsPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

> Reading from Database

```
public Vector getData(Vector data) throws ParseException{
    try {
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from connection_records");
        while (resultSet.next()){
            Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();

            for (int i = 1; i <= 11 ; i++)
            {
                row.addElement(resultSet.getString(i));
            }
            data.addElement( row );
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnections.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Don't use bold highlighting on the text of your question. Bold highlighting is used to emphasize a word or sentence, not the entire question.

Comment: How do you expect this to work? A JTable uses renderers to display data. If you use the combo box as a renderer then you will only ever see one item. A JTable also uses editors. The editor is how you change the data. So when you edit the cell a combo box can be used to display multiple items, but then when you select an item only that item is store in the model.

Comment: Sorry for posting it in a wrong format.

Comment: So what is the solution according to you? Because I have multiple data (ArrayList) in column which I want to display in an efficient manner in JTable that is why I have chosen JComboBox. But now you are telling me  renderers are used to display data.

Comment: If you want to see all the items at once you do what you are currently doing. You could limit the column with and use a tooltip on the cell to see all the values. Or you could create a custom render. Maybe something like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955595/how-to-display-multiple-lines-in-a-jtable-cell/32793088#32793088. Or maybe you change your database to have a single column for each type of Document and then you just store a Boolean value to indicate which Documents you have. Then the JTable would also just have a column with a check box for each document.

Comment: Thank you i think your solution is useful.